# iOS how to display dictionary keys into table cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, dictionary

I have a dictionary declared as `"res"`. This `"res"` contains response of JSON data.

I did a `valueforkey = "id"` to retrieve out the list of id.

When I want to display each id into the tableview it turns out it only displays the same id repetively.

Here is my tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [res count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViews dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    for(int i = 0; i<res.count; i++)
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[res  valueForKey:@"id"]];

    return cell;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    return view;
}
```

When i NSLOG out the res with value "id" :

```
icon = [res valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"icon: %@", icon);
```

it shows:

```
icon: (
    300122,
    300228,
    300235,
    300272,
    300265,
    300242,
    300198,
    300135,
    300282,
    300255,
    300245,
    300248,
    300185,
    300118,
    300275,
    300295,
    300005,
    300062,
    300068,
    300055,
    300095,
    300008,
    300018,
    300015,
    300058,
    300012,
    300085,
    300038,
    300105,
    300002,
    300072,
    300022,
    300025,
    300028,
    300035,
    300258,
    300088,
    300262,
    300128,
    300215,
    300142,
    300078,
    300205,
    300315,
    300238,
    300302,
    300232,
    300285,
    300132,
    300102
)
```

Question is how do i display each id on each cell in the tableview?

Comment: What is the use of  for loop inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath. why you have written that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an array of allKeys

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[yourDictionary allKeys]];'
```

then just set your tableView `dataSource` using this array.

e.g

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViews dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<res.count; i++)
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}---> This code is meaning less ..why we need to loop??? for loop is meaning less we can achieve just by using
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I am sorry, I copied his `cellForRowAtIndexPath`code and updated where I wanted, please see updated answer

Comment: ..Yeah its perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

Replace numberOfRowsInSection with:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSArray *arrIds = (NSArray *)[res valueForKey:@"id"];
    return arrIds.count;
}
```

And replace

```
for(int i = 0; i<res.count; i++)
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[res  valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

with

```
NSArray *arrIds = (NSArray *)[res valueForKey:@"id"];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[arrIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your **@"id"** values in one array as follows;

```
NSArray *icon = [res valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"icon: %@", icon);
```

Then use that array to display values in TableView cell as follows;

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViews dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[icon objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line below

```
for(int i = 0; i<res.count; i++)
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[res  valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

with line

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[[res  valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

your for loop logic is not correct to achieve the goal. We have tableView's default indexPath object to fetch current row in tableview, so fetch the value from your at the tableview's indexPath from your array.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
ViewDidload{
NSArray * iconArray = [res allKeys];
} 


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViews dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@",[iconArray   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
```

}